# compare kubernetes ingress with openshift routes

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

Am studying ingress and found it somewhat similar to openshifts routes.
How is a kubernetes ingress different from openshift route or vice versa?
Thanks.
R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenShift also supports the concept of ingress as it is built on top of Kubernetes. Like an ingress the concept of an OpenShift route is just a way of directing external traffic towards your cluster.

An OpenShift route however only supports HTTP/HTTPS traffic. The router is essentially HAProxy running within a Pod(s) within the cluster which handles traffic to the route. Typically TLS is edge terminated at the router and the request between the router and the destination IP is over HTTP. However you can configure your route to deal with TLS within the application itself.

When a HTTP/HTTPS request hits the router it uses the service name to get a list of Pod IP addresses which are fronted by the service and sends traffic directly to the Pod IP over the software defined network.

Comment: why does openshift use routes if it offers only a subset of ingress?

Comment: I believe OpenShift released with routes before the concept of ingress had stabilised in Kubernetes. Although I am open to correction on that. You can still go ahead and use ingress on OpenShift